# Php echo woocommerce price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hi i am trying to echo with php the woocommerce product price in a specific area at my site. But it only works for single  products. Not for variable products. What i must do?

Comment: where do you want to display the price? on single product's page or another page?

Comment: I want to display it on product page. But all my products are variable not single products

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `get_variation_prices( $for_display = false )` method or `get_variation_regular_price( $min_or_max = 'min', $for_display = false )`

Something like this:

```
global $product;
var_dump( $product->get_variation_prices() );
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L97

```
/**
 * Get the min or max variation regular price.
 *
 * @param  string  $min_or_max Min or max price.
 * @param  boolean $for_display If true, prices will be adapted for display based on the `woocommerce_tax_display_shop` setting (including or excluding taxes).
 * @return string
 */
public function get_variation_regular_price( $min_or_max = 'min', $for_display = false ) {
    $prices = $this->get_variation_prices( $for_display );
    $price  = 'min' === $min_or_max ? current( $prices['regular_price'] ) : end( $prices['regular_price'] );
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_variation_regular_price', $price, $this, $min_or_max, $for_display );
}
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L80

```
/**
 * Get an array of all sale and regular prices from all variations. This is used for example when displaying the price range at variable product level or seeing if the variable product is on sale.
 *
 * @param  bool $for_display If true, prices will be adapted for display based on the `woocommerce_tax_display_shop` setting (including or excluding taxes).
 * @return array Array of RAW prices, regular prices, and sale prices with keys set to variation ID.
 */
public function get_variation_prices( $for_display = false ) {
    $prices = $this->data_store->read_price_data( $this, $for_display );
    foreach ( $prices as $price_key => $variation_prices ) {
        $prices[ $price_key ] = $this->sort_variation_prices( $variation_prices );
    }
    return $prices;
}
```